# Java: using JMF with Codenvy IDE?

Tags: java, video, package, media, codenvy

I'm making a game and wish to load an introduction video before the game starts, just introducing the story line. However, I'm using [Codenvy online IDE](http://codenvy.com), and it doesn't include the JMF package. When I try to import `javax.media.*`, I get an error saying it can't be found. Is there a way I can import it into my project? I'm using Maven standalone GUI as my project type.

Thanks

Comment: JMF is a separate download.

Comment: @Kayaman yes but how would i apply it so that i can use it in my codenvy maven project?

Comment: Ah, some sort of online IDE. Might be impossible. Why not use a non-online IDE?

Comment: @Kayaman it is a project used and shared with many developers, around the world. It needs to be online. Also I use it while i am at school (I'm currently doing A-Level computer science), and the IT department refuse to install a Java IDE because I'm the only one in the school who programmes in java for a school project

Comment: In the real world when developing a project globally, you use a version control system such as `git` and naturally a real IDE instead of an online one. Too bad about your school, but at least you can install and learn to use them on your home computer (if you're planning on continuing with programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you import this package when working on a project locally? The import you have mentioned works ok offline but doesn't in Codenvy?

Comment: Codenvy's maven simply doesn't have the package in the core dependencies. I've looked into trying to set up a `.jar` in my maven dependencies, but can't get it to work. I can get the `JMF.jar` file but i try to add dependency code to my `pom.xml` file and it doesn't like `<dependencies>` tag

Comment: Maven installed on a Codenvy builder instance does not differ from Maven that you have locally (well, except for you cannot modify its settings.xml).

If you want to use a local jar, upload it to the project and add it as a dependency. Here's a brief guide on how to do it - http://docs.codenvy.com/user/technology-specific-features/#upload-local-libs

Comment: @karlsson I have tried this, but when I build the `.jar`, it gives an error saying the tad `<dependency>` is wrong/isn't recognized?

Comment: Just checked it and it works. Are you sure you followed the tutorial and built the correct repo structure?